# ¿Error al agregar imagenes "Unable to load asset"?

Tags: flutter, dart

Soy nuevo en flutter, tengo un error al cargar las imagenes de una carpeta "lib/assets/", al entrar a la page que carga las imagenes obtengo el error

The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: lib/assets/t2 Carpinteria.jpg

Tengo de la siguiente forma mi codigo que carga las imagenes, esta dentro de un ListView.builder

```
ListTile(
                        title: Text(servicios[index]['nombre']),
                        subtitle: Text(servicios[index]['descripcion']),
                        trailing: Stack(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                width: 60,
                                height: 70,
                                child: Image.asset(
                                    "lib/assets/${servicios[index]['imagen']}")),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

si cargo el asset individualmente:
"lib/assets/t2 Carpinteria.jpg")),
si me carga la imagen.

Y en mi pubspec.yaml ya agrege la ruta de los assets

assets:
- lib/assets/

pero me sigue marcando el error, alguna solucion??

Comment: Que estás guardando en ${servicios[index]['imagen']} ? unicamente el nombre de la imagen con la extensión o la ruta como tal?

Comment: solo el nombre de la imagen, ${servicios[index]['imagen']} me regresa "t2 Carpinteria.jpg"

Comment: intenta quitandole el espacio al nombre de la imagen y vuelve a cargar tu proyecto

Comment: @krozer lib/assets/ se encuentra dentro de /assets/ de tu proyecto? agrega como lo definiste en tu archivo .yaml.

Comment: ya le quite el espacio y aun asi me marca el error
Si, se encuentra dentro de lib/assets
"assets/imagen.jpg" si lo carga, al momento de poner ${servicios[index]['imagen']}  es cuando marca error

Comment: @krozer el directorio definido en tu proyecto donde se encuentra la imagen y que esta en la raiz de tu proyecto es : lib/assets/  ?

Comment: si, esta en lib/assets/, en el pubspec ya lo puse - lib/assets/, pero no carga las imagenes

Comment: @krozer , agregue respuesta, en cuanto a tu pregunta " hay alguna manera de que me carge las imagenes desde lib/pages/assets/?", solo agrega este directorio dentro de tu archivo pubspec.yaml en la sección "assets:" pero te sugiero usar otro directorio diferente a /lib ya que este se usa para bibliotecas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sería bueno que intentes almacener en  `${servicios[index]['imagen']}` la ruta de la imagen, yo tengo un proyecto similar, solo que en vez de un `asset`, uso `File` pero porque lo requiero, si está bien que tu uses el `Image.asset`:

```
           Image.file(
                File(_searchList[index].foto!),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
```

si te das cuenta yo no ubico primero la ruta y luego la `concateno` con el `index` de la foto, directamente pongo la ruta almacenada en la variable "foto", obviamente se mostraría la imagen dependiendo del `index`, me avisas si este método te funciona.

ACTUALIZACIÓN: EJEMPLO LISTVIEW CON IMAGENES

```
class Ejemplo extends StatefulWidget {
  Ejemplo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Ejemplo> createState() => _EjemploState();
}

class _EjemploState extends State<Ejemplo> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> servicios = [
    {
      "nombre": 'Ejemplo 1',
      "descripcion": 'descripcion ejemplo 1',
      "imagen": "cambio_aceite.jpeg",
    },
    {
      "nombre": 'Ejemplo 2',
      "descripcion": "descripcion ejemplo 2",
      "imagen": "cuatro.jpeg",
    },
    {
      "nombre": 'Ejemplo 3',
      "descripcion": "descripcion ejemplo 3",
      "imagen": "conexion_wifi.png",
    }
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: listaOpciones(),
    );
  }

  Widget listaOpciones() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text('Example App: List Images'),
        Container(
          height: 400,
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: servicios.length,
              itemBuilder: (itemBuilder, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(servicios[index]['nombre']),
                  subtitle: Text(servicios[index]['descripcion']),
                  trailing: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          width: 60,
                          height: 70,
                          child: Image.asset(
                              "assets/${servicios[index]['imagen']}")),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ya lo intente, y me sigue saliendo el mismo error:

The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset:

el vscode me lo marca en
PaintingBinding.instance!.imageCache!.evict(key);
      rethrow;

Comment: acabé de actualizar mi respuesta con un código de ejemplo tratando de hacer lo que quieres hacer,  estoy usando el image.asset al igual que tú, intenta copiar este código, entenderlo y ver en que puedes estar fallando y cambia las imagenes que yo estoy utilizando, para ver si se reflejan en tu app. Date cuenta que yo solo utilizo una carpeta para guardar las imagenes "assets", para que aumentes el "lib"

Comment: Si funciono, tuve que poner la carpeta lib/pages/assets/, ya que en lib/assets/ no me cargaba las imagenes y aparecia el error, hay alguna manera de que me carge las imagenes desde lib/pages/assets/?

Comment: No es recomendable poner la carpeta assets dentro de la carpeta lib, generalmente se la crea dentro del proyecto como tal, junto a las carpetas: android, build, fonts,ios, lib, esa carpeta de asset la tienes que crear dentro del proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero revisar la consola, ahí se despliega regularmente un mensaje cuando no se puede cargar alguna imagen, por ejemplo:

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/icons/ic_lancher_iris_languages.png
```

Mencionas que cargas sin problema la imagen desde la ruta:

"lib/assets/t2 Carpinteria.jpg"

y carga de la imagen se realiza mediante :

```
 child: Image.asset(
                     "lib/assets/${servicios[index]['imagen']}")),
```

Debes asegurar lo siguiente:

**1** )En la raiz de tu proyecto debes tener el directorio `lib/assets`, mismo que debe ser registrado en tu archivo `pubspec.yaml` de la siguiente forma:

```
  assets:
      - lib/assets/
```

**2** ) Debes asegurar que el valor de `${servicios[index]['imagen']}` sea en verdad "`t2 Carpinteria.jpg`"  ya que si el nombre es incorrecto, esto puede ser la causa por la cual no se muestra la imagen.

El problema se debe generalmente a que la ruta o nombre del archivo son incorrectos. Por cierto los nombres con espacios como en el caso de tu archivo "t2 Carpinteria.jpg" son permitidos y se deben cargar sin problema.